# Trying to get connecting Dabase Name using java

Tags: java, teradata

```
conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = conn.getMetaData();

oracleSchema = databaseMetaData.getUserName(); // Oracle gives me database name i am connecting to....
```

But is there is any specific method which gives me teradata database name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you don't include a database in your connection string, you don't have a "default database".  As far as I know, including the database name in your connection is the same as executing `DATABASE <database name>` in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using SQL to get the database name. I think for teradata it is

```
SELECT defaultdatabase,sessionno
FROM Dbc.Sessioninfo where username='USR_NAME' ;
```

Comment: Simply use `SELECT DATABASE;` instead

Comment: yes, I did not find any programmatic solution other than using query!..thanks@dnoeth